# ValueEventListener triggered onDataChange method just once

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am facing a problem with Firebase Realtime Database in my Android app.

What I am trying is to update the list in Realtime. But the update only works on app start. It doesn't update automatically. So, I need to restart the app whenever want update.

Is there any missing part? I appreciate for any help. Thanks

Problem: 
Listener triggered `onDataChange` method only in app restart. Data are correct. But listener doesn't work after that.

Code:

```
mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mPostRef = mRef.child(DbUtils.POST_CHILD);
mPostRef.keepSynced(true);

mPostRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<Post> objList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot objSnapShot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            Post obj = objSnapShot.getValue(Post.class);
            obj.setKey(objSnapShot.getKey());
            objList.add(obj);
        }
        mAdapter.addAllAndNotify(objList);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.i("Posts", "Listener was canceled");
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure the data is changing?  Try using the Firebase console to change the data.  I ran your code with version 10.0.1 and onDataChange() fires when the data changes.

Comment: I changed data in console. Code doesn't not work. 
Does your data update whenever you change? (I am using 9.8.0, will try with 10.0.1). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Add a `Log` statement to `onDataChange()` to see when the callback fires.

Comment: I tried log level for debug. It doesn't even fire callback.

Comment: Are you sure you are changing the correct data?  Try enabling Firebase debug output: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG);`

Comment: If `onDataChange()` doesn't even trigger on subsequent changes, it sounds like your app is losing its connection to the Firebase servers. You might be able to glean something about that from logcat by enabling debug logging: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the bug.

The fact is Firebase **doesn't support multiple connection**. 
So, I removed all other DatabaseReference from my activity. And it works now.

Thanks people who tried to help me.